# Rails nested form is not inserting into database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

Ok so I've got a rails nested form for two tables. It inserts everything into one table but not in the other. I've looked up all the examples around that I could get my hands on and no matter what I do it does not seem to work.

Here are my models:

User:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :addresses, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses
end
```

Adress:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

This is my form:

```
= form_for @user do |f|
  - if @user.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
      %h2= "#{pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this user from being saved:"
      %ul
        - @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
          %li= msg
  %ul
  .field
    = f.label :first_name
    = f.text_field :first_name
  .field
    = f.label :last_name
    = f.text_field :last_name
  .field
    = f.label :password
    = f.text_field :password
  .field
    = f.label :email
    = f.text_field :email
  = f.fields_for :address do |address|
    .field 
      = address.label :country 
      = address.text_field :country
    .field 
      = address.label :state
      = address.text_field :state
    .field
      = address.label :city 
      = address.text_field :city
    .field 
      = address.label :zip_code
      = address.text_field :zip_code 
  .actions
    = f.submit 'Save'
```

Finally there's the controller, which I believe is the source of my problem, I've looked up countless examples on how to do this and it seems like every one does it differently. Anyway here it is:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /users/new
  def new
    @user = User.new
    @addresses = @user.addresses.build
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /users/1
  # PATCH/PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.json
  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: 'User was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :password, :email, 
      address_attributes: [:country, :state, :city])
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
= fields_for :address do |address|
```

Would be

```
= f.fields_for :addresses do |address|
```

and in your controller, it would be `addresses_attributes`

```
def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :password, :email, 
      addresses_attributes: [:country, :state, :city])
    end
```

You can use [cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) gem for nested attributes. It's good and quite easy to implement.

Comment: @Argus, Great. I recommend you to check the gem I've mentioned.

Comment: I will do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please rewrite the following line of code in your form, because of `has_many` relation, `address` will be change to `addresses` in `plural` form.

```
  = fields_for :address do |address|
```

Replace to

```
   = f.fields_for :addresses do |address|
```

And `user_params` should be change a bit, like `addresses_attributes` instead of `address_attributes`

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :password, :email, 
  addresses_attributes: [:country, :state, :city])
end
```

Comment: @Argus can you please check now ?